# What is Relationship between entities and buckets in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have some entities created in datastore mode. It's not clear to me how to find the bucket they are stored in.

If I go in to all my buckets using the bucket browser I can't see any of my entities, but can see them if I go go > Storage > DataStore > Entities via hamburger UI from web console.

Are entities stored in a bucket? If so, how do I know which one they were stored in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, entities are not stored in a bucket.  Entities are stored in a database.  Buckets are for storing files.

Comment: Agreed. [Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#buckets) and [Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#working_with_entities) both stem from two different GCP products: Cloud Storage and Cloud Datastore. One is for storing files and the other one is a NoSQL database.

Comment: Yeah I get that. The confusing thing for me was that the docs indicate to operate on entities with the glcoud CLI tool you need to set a bucket env var...so I was trying to figure out why. See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#set_up_your_environment

Answer (score 1):

You can **export** your entities from **Datastore** and store them in a **Cloud Storage** bucket as a **backup**.

This is what's explained in the [Exporting and Importing Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#set_up_your_environment) document.

As @gaefan said, Datastore is a NoSQL database and Cloud Storage is for storing files, so there is no "live" connection between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can move entities between projects. In this case, in the source project you export to a bucket, and then you position yourself in the destination project to import the bucket.

This is useful for backups, testing environments, etc.